# Jquery plugin - Tree Context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Can you suggest a context-menu plugin that supports nesting menu items? When clicking on an item, if the item has sub-items, it should open a secondary menu.

**EDIT**

Like [this](http://www.contextmenu.net/screenshot/screenshot_windows_explorer_shell_context_menu.jpg) but for jquery

Comment: Describe what you mean by "open a secondary menu" in more detail please as this could mean many things.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao,
I created recently a **jQuery plugin**, hope this might help you

(view source for codes)

[DEMO SITE (jQ treeMenu)](http://www.roko.x10.mx/treeMenu/)

[image]